# I am trying to create a Azure VMr module with all its other properties

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

Trying to take VM id in VM extension resource also vm is created using for each loop. please find below code

```
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "windowsvm" {
  for_each = var.virtual_machines
  name                = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.LBS_rg.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.LBS_rg.location
  size                = each.value.size
  admin_username      = each.value.admin_username
  admin_password      = each.value.admin_password

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vm-extensions" {
  for_each = var.vm-ext
  name                 = each.value.name
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.windowsvm[each.value.virtual_machines_name].id
  publisher            =  each.value.publisher        #Microsoft.Compute
  type                 = each.value.type              #CustomScriptExtension
  type_handler_version =  each.value.type_handler_version   #1.10
```

Now when i am taking the id of the VM created in the other resource which is VM extension code
it is giving me following error :-

```
virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.windowsvm[each.value.virtual_machines_name].id

each.value is object with 4 attributes

 This object does not have an attribute named "virtual_machines_name"
```

Comment: You promised to include code...

Comment: included teh code

Comment: Is it really `virtual_machines_name` (plural) and not `virtual_machine_name` (singular)?

Comment: its virtual_machines_names

Comment: I agree with @knittl error seems to be syntax issue try using virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.windowsvm[each.value.virtual_machine_name].id

Comment: Is this Terraform syntax? The tags only mention "azure"

Comment: Can you link the relevant docs? I'm having a hard time finding them

Comment: "each.value is object with 4 attributes" ← which 4 attributes exist on the object?

Comment: i did try the same virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.windowsvm[each.value.virtual_machine_name].id  Vinay its still not working

Comment: @SarahPotrick can you please share the total code info you tried?

Comment: I am unable to attach the code in the comment

Comment: @SarahPotrick you can update the query asked.

Comment: these are the 4 attributes i am assuming VM id, publisher , type and  type_handler_version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried trying to create an Azure VM module with all its other properties I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The error message suggests that the object you're iterating over in your `azurerm_virtual_machine_extension` resource does not have an attribute called `virtual_machines_name`. This means your `each.value.virtual_machines_name` is not correctly referencing the VM names.

To overcome this I tried a configuration that works fine with the same configuration and code changes as expected.

**My terraform configuration:**

**main.tf:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "existing_rg" {
  name = var.resource_group_name
}

# Virtual Network and Subnet Configuration
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main_vnet" {
  name                = "mainvk-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing_rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "main_subnet" {
  name                 = "vkinternal"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing_rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main_vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

# Network Interface Configuration
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "vm_nic" {
  for_each = var.virtual_machines

  name                = "${each.value.name}-nic"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing_rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.main_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    # public_ip_address_id if you need public IPs
  }
}

# Virtual Machine Configuration
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "windowsvm" {
  for_each = var.virtual_machines

  name                = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing_rg.name
  location            = var.location
  size                = each.value.size
  admin_username      = each.value.admin_username
  admin_password      = each.value.admin_password

  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.vm_nic[each.key].id]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    # other required configurations for os_disk
  }

    source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2019-Datacenter"  # Adjust the SKU as per your requirement
    version   = "latest"
  }

  # other required configurations like OS profile, etc.
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vm_extensions" {
  for_each = var.vm_extensions

  name                 = each.value.name
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.windowsvm[each.value.virtual_machine_name].id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"

  settings = jsonencode({
    "fileUris"         = ["SAS_URL"],  # Replace with the actual URL of your script
    "commandToExecute" = "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File powershell.ps1"
  })
}
```

Make sure you upload your Powershell script in the container blob and the relevant permission for SAS_URL for that Powershell script.

**variables.tf:**

```
variable "virtual_machines" {
  description = "Configuration for each virtual machine"
  type = map(object({
    name             = string
    size             = string
    admin_username   = string
    admin_password   = string
  }))
}

variable "vm_extensions" {
  description = "Configuration for VM extensions"
  type = map(object({
    name                  = string
    virtual_machine_name  = string
    publisher             = string
    type                  = string
    type_handler_version  = string
  }))
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group"
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The location/region in which to create the resources"
  type        = string
}
```

**terraform.tfvars:**

```
virtual_machines = {
  "vm1" = {
    name             = "vk-vm1"
    size             = "Standard_DS1_v2"
    admin_username   = "adminuser"
    admin_password   = "AdminPassword123!"
  },
  "vm2" = {
    name             = "vk-vm2"
    size             = "Standard_DS1_v2"
    admin_username   = "adminuser"
    admin_password   = "AdminPassword123!"
  }
}

vm_extensions = {
  "extension1" = {
    name                  = "vk-extension1"
    virtual_machine_name  = "vm1"
    publisher             = "Microsoft.Compute"
    type                  = "CustomScriptExtension"
    type_handler_version  = "1.10"
  },
  "extension2" = {
    name                  = "vk-extension2"
    virtual_machine_name  = "vm2"
    publisher             = "Microsoft.Compute"
    type                  = "CustomScriptExtension"
    type_handler_version  = "1.10"
  }
}

resource_group_name = "sakavya"
location            = "westus2"
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Soo… it's a typo? "each.value.virtual_machine_name != each.value.virtual_machines_name"?

Comment: @knittl there is a typo as well as the declaration of info related to VM ID, publisher, type, and type_handler_version under the module section.

Comment: Hi vinay B this worked i got the logic now. thankyou so much. This logic wworked for me